# I have found a bug when UINavigationController pop with animation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I did a test with the UINavigationController, when I click the back to First button, the navigation controller will pop to the FirstController with a animation, but when I click quickly, during in the animation's duration, it will do push SecondController again and again, also it will create multi-secondControllers.

Again I do another test, when I touch in the Push Button's frame, I found the problem had gone.

So I thought Apple have known that the Push Button should not deal with touch events when it's during in a animation. The problem is Apple do another thing with the navigation button, Apple expands the navigation button's receiver bounds to make it easy to touch, so the problem come out.

Please lose sight of my poor english. I hope Apple can fix this problem.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, its probably not the best location to put a button which pushes a controller. I would put such a button on the right leaving the left for operations which take you back, cancel etc...

Your problem will be that when you click more than once during animation, you end up causing a new Push to be activated while the Pop is still in progress which causes some sort of internal looping to occur in iOS. If you want to keep the button on the left, then the following should fix the issue:

In your FirstController,  in `viewDidLoad`  set the Push button `enabled` property to `NO`;

In your FirstController, in `viewDidAppear` set the Push button `enabled` property to `YES`;

In your FirstController, in `viewDidDisappear` set the Push button `enabled` property to `NO`;

This should make sure that the Push button is only active once the pop has completed preventing multiple clicks during animation.